# How to duplicate an input when checkbox is checked on Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to duplicate an `input` if a checkbox is checked. If it is not, then do not write anything on the second `checkbox`.

This is the code that references to those elements:

```
<form name="myCustomForm">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkDuplicate.value1" ng-true-value="{{myCustomForm.ownerName.$viewValue}}" ng-false-value="''"/>
    <input ng-model="ownerName" placeholder="Enter your name..." name="ownerName"  id="ownerName" disabled>
    <input ng-value="{{checkDuplicate.value1}}" placeholder="Enter the name of the house in which you live..." name="houseOwnerName" required>
</form>
```

On my controller I have the following to initialize the checkbox:

```
$scope.checkDuplicate = {
   value1 : true
};
```

***What I am trying to do***

If a checkbox is checked then the second input will be autocompleted with the value of the first one. If not, then the second input will be empty until the user gives to it some value.

---

I have two problems here:

***First one***

If I set manually `true` or `false` depending on the state of the checkbox (I mean `ng-true-value="'true'"` and `ng-false-value="'false'"`) it retrieves well the value that the `checkbox` has.

But if I try to retrieve my `input` value as shown above I get an empty value (it does not matter if it has some value or not, it is always empty).

***Second one***

If I put my code as I have shown above it only gets the value first time (when the page is loaded), but not the following times I change the `checkbox` value.

Nevertheless, if I try to retrieve the value out of the `input` value I can get the value of the checkbox properly. I mean, if I do `<span>{{checkDuplicate.value1}}</span>` it is shown properly.

I have tried using `ng-change` but without success.

How can I solve these errors or how can I duplicate my `input` in a proper way when `checkbox` is checked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your concern? if the checkbox is checked then dynamically input should be added?

Comment: @RohanKawade No, I mean that if a checkbox is checked then the second input will be autocompleted with the value of the first one. If not, then the second input will be empty until the user gives to it some value. Now I will add this info to the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the variable to track input or not. There is a working example.

*Explanation*

I changed the checkboxes `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` it is giving us a variable name witch you are using in `ng-model` of `ownerName input`. Then i changed duplicate inputs `ng-model` variable. It is changing *depeding on checkboxes value*. If checkbox is checked it is tracking `$scope.inputs.name` if it is not `$scope.inputs.text`

```js
    var app = angular.module("app",[]);
    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

    $scope.inputs = {};

    $scope.checkDuplicate = {
       value1 : 'text'
    };

    })
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
      
      
      <form name="myCustomForm">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkDuplicate.value1" ng-true-value="name" ng-false-value="text"/>
        <input ng-model="inputs.name" placeholder="Enter your name..." name="ownerName"  id="ownerName" >
        <input ng-model="inputs[checkDuplicate.value1]" placeholder="Enter the name of the house in which you live..." name="houseOwnerName" required>
    </form>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So if I want to change an `input` value... Should I declare it on the `$scope` to be able to change?

Comment: You are already declaring it on scope. Just name it and use it by name to referance it

Comment: @Error404 i edited the answer to track input not its value

Comment: I mean that if I tried to set before the value manually (with true and false values) it did not change. The only one difference that I see is that you are creating this new variable called `inputs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form name="myCustomForm">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkDuplicate.value1" ng-true-value="
        {{myCustomForm.ownerName.$viewValue}}" ng-false-value="''"
          ng-click="updateOwnerName()"/>
  <input ng-model="ownerName" placeholder="Enter your name..." 
         name="ownerName"  id="ownerName" disabled>
  <input ng-model="houseOwnerName" ng-value="{{checkDuplicate.value1}}" 
         placeholder="Enter the name of the house in which you live..." 
         name="houseOwnerName" required>
```

Add a click event to the checkbox.

Assign ng-model to the second input.

now in the controller

```
     $scope.checkDuplicate = {
          value1 : false   
      };

     $scope.updateOwnerName=function(){
         // write your auto complete logic here
         // let the value to be displayed in 2nd input is "MARS"
           if(checkDuplicate.value1){
                 $scope.houseOwnerName="MARS";
              }
           else{
                 $scope.houseOwnerName="";
               }

        }
```